# Default pom.xml for new Eclipse Maven projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2eclipse

I'm on Eclipse Neon.1 and when I create new Maven projects I get a default `pom.xml` with this content:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>test</name>

</project>
```

How can I modify this default template? I'd like to add some properties, for example

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>test</name>

    <properties>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Of course I can create my own archetype and use it to have this pom, but the `m2e` plugin is so configurable I hope this is possible without an archetype.

Comment: Maybe you could add your properties into a code snippet and edit the pom.xml file before you move on.

Answer (score 2):

The question is, which archetype is actually used, when you skip the archetype selection. My first thought was, that it must be `maven-archetype-quickstart`. This would be the default [when stepping into the archetype selection](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/b9f968987af5dfa309b5655c695e381ac55b7252/org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/ui/internal/wizards/MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.java#L1030).

But the sad truth is, that no archetype is used at all and the POM is filled directly with the minimal set of values (groupId/artifactId/version). [This is hard coded](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/b9f968987af5dfa309b5655c695e381ac55b7252/org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/ui/internal/wizards/MavenProjectWizard.java#L218) and cannot be changed or extended with your properties. Sorry.